# iOS statusBar background goes to black after transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm pushing from a VC1 inside a UINavigationController to a VC2. VC2 has a transparent navigationBar.

In viewDidLoad inside VC2:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
```

When i push the back button i want to restore the navigationBar as it was (green color), so inside viewWillDissapear i have the following:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .green
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .green
```

But i get this weird black status bar while transitioning:

[image: strange black line on top][image]

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/ivangodfather/firstSteps/blob/master/TestNavigation.zip)

Here is expected transition:
[image]

Comment: This is not about statusBar background. Try changing it light content and you will be able to see status bar on both screen. This is something with your navigationBar which goes black when transit and your status bar is dark so it looks like status bar issue.

Comment: so i would like to change the navigationBar transit color to avoid this issue like twitter has

Comment: When setting the `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear` then you see window which is black too. So set your window background color to something but not black then you will see the difference.

Comment: I don't have Twitter so could you please add the same animation for twitter too?

Comment: @TheTiger i added an image to show want im aiming for

Comment: In the attached image I can see only title is fade and navbar color is white.

Comment: Take a `UIView` add your title label on it, Hide the `navigationBar` and set its background color with alpha while animating instead of doing it on `navigationBar`.

Comment: i want to use navigationBar since i want back buttons from it and so on... this is just a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try below,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .clear

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
}
```

and

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .green
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .green

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
}
```

Comment: this is getting better, the problem is that i also need the isTranslucent to true since i want to be transparent, and when i go back i need to set back to false

Comment: You can set self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true, it will give you same output

Comment: @Godfather is it helpful to you?

Comment: it helps, but its not exactly as i shown. With this the navigationBar appears sunddently after transition but thx anyway!